# warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c

I'm new to C, and for a simple task I was asked to make a 4d array.

I started by making a regular array, which would print the amount of items you tell it to.

I tried to then expand it to be composed of 2 arrays, which I haven't gotten to work.

It gives me this error, what can I do to make an array within an array?

```
#include \<stdio.h\>

int main(){

    int arrayprint;
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 30;
    int d = 40;
    int* array1[] = {a, b};
    int* array2[] = {c, d};
    int** topArray[] = {array1, array2};
    int i;
    
    printf("Amount of matrix items to print? (Maximum 2):\n");
    scanf("%d", &arrayprint);
    printf("\nYou chose %d items.", arrayprint);
    
    for (i = 0; i < arrayprint; i++) {
    printf("\n%d", topArray[i]);
    }

}
```

I had this code before with just a regular array, and it worked great.

But it doesn't seem to like how it is now, it gives me errors, but also works and prints what looks like memory values?

Comment: too many * here `int* array1[] = {a, b};`, you want `int array1[] = {a, b};`, same elsewhere. You are decalring an array of pointers to ints, you want an array of ints

Comment: `int* array1[] = {a, b};` declare an array that holds pointers. It's possible you meant `int* array1[] = {&a, &b};` to put pointers to values in the array. If you wanted to put the integer values in an array you'd want `int array1[] = {a, b};` and `int* topArray...`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja
That made the error go away, doing 
`int array1[] = {a, b};`
`int array2[] = {c, d};`
`int* topArray[] = {array1, array2};`
But it's still printing out something different, the output is:
You chose 2 items.
6422272
6422264

Comment: Creating and indexing a 4d array is not a simple task; it is fraught with danger. Suggest clipping a maximum-sized: `array[2][2][2][2]; size_t s0, s1, s2, s3;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring arrays, you don't use pointers, you only use pointers to refer to the array in its entirety.

```
int nums[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {1,2};
```

Essentially, subtract one `*` from anywhere you used it. Here's a version you can copy and paste if you'd like:
(assuming both arrays are the same width)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int arrayprint;
  int a = 10;
  int b = 20;
  int c = 30;
  int d = 40;
  int array1[] = {a, b};
  int array2[] = {c, d};
  int* topArray[] = {array1, array2};

  printf("Amount of matrix items to print? (Maximum 2):\n");
  scanf("%d", &arrayprint);
  printf("\nYou chose %d items.", arrayprint);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayprint; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayprint; j++) {
      printf("\n%d", topArray[i][j]);
      //when dealing with square multidimensional arrays, the order of i and j don't matter.
    }
  }
}
```

Also, it's best practice to use `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `#include \<stdio.h\>`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome man, and thanks for the tip
I knew I had to make another for loop but I wasn't really sure where to start

Comment: Tysm! I'm glad this helped you!